# Unreal Engine C++ Get paused sound cue time played

Tags: c++, audio, unreal-engine4

So I'm writing now some audio handling in C++ for my game and I've encountered a problem. 
What i need to to is have possibility to pause sound cue at any time and get the time it has already played. For example:

I have a cue that has 10 seconds. It was playing for 3 seconds. So i need to get out from it that 3 seconds, so I can after let's say restarting the game and loading save play remaining 7 seconds of the sound. Is there any function for it? I've searched for it for quite a time but never found anything usefull.

I'm using `UAudioComponent::SpawnSound(2D/Attached/AtLocation)` functions.

Comment: consider asking a UE4 question on https://answers.unrealengine.com/, you can get faster response

Comment: I will, but i know here I can find lot of smart people so it's worth trying :3